# Inserting multiple records into different placeholders in php and error in grid system

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have been developing a website to display different coupons and the data is taken from database.It has 4 columns containing id,name,no of coupons,caption as shown here[image: Image is shown below].

Now main idea is to create a featured store section in php page which contains image which takes storename.jpeg as source to get the image. Also it has a div displays no of coupons and a caption. How to write a query to individually access these 3 columns? Also the grid system is not working correctly in smaller devices some are not in right position. Code snippet is added below

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();    
 
    $('.thumbnail').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(250); //.fadeIn(250)
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(250); //.fadeOut(205)
        }
    ); 
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
 
.thumbnail {
    position:relative;  
    overflow:hidden;
}
 
.caption {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    background:rgba(66, 139, 202, 0.75);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:2%;
    display: none;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff !important;
    z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
//Step1
 $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","sai123"); 
 if (!$db) {
 die("Database connection failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
 }
//Step2
 $db_select = mysql_select_db("AskCoupon.com",$db);
 if (!$db_select) {
 die("Database selection also failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
 }
 // echo "Database connection Established";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Promotional codes,Coupons,Deals and many more</title>

   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
   
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php $query = "select * from featured_stores"; $result = mysql_query($query);?>
  <?php if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());?>
  
  
<div class="container">
  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Placeholder Coupon no</h4>
                    <p>Get exiting deals here</p>
                    
                </div>
                <img src="img/flipkart.jpeg" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div>
      
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Placeholder Coupon no</h4>
                    <p>Get exiting deals here</p>
                    
                </div>
                <img src="img/paytm.jpeg" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Placeholder Coupon no</h4>
                    <p>Get exiting deals here</p>
                    
                </div>
                <img src="img/savaari.jpeg" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Placeholder Coupon no</h4>
                    <p>Get exiting deals here</p>
                    
                </div>
                <img src="img/uber.jpeg" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Placeholder Coupon no</h4>
                    <p>Get exiting deals here</p>
                    
                </div>
                <img src="img/foodpanda.jpeg" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Placeholder Coupon no</h4>
                    <p>Get exiting deals here</p>
                    
                </div>
                <img src="img/mobikwik.jpeg" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div>       
        
  </div>






  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Placeholder Coupon no</h4>
                    <p>Get exiting deals here</p>
                    
                </div>
                <img src="img/zoomcar.jpeg" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div>
      
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Placeholder Coupon no</h4>
                    <p>Get exiting deals here</p>
                    
                </div>
                <img src="img/jabong.jpeg" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Placeholder Coupon no</h4>
                    <p>Get exiting deals here</p>
                    
                </div>
                <img src="img/tinyowl.jpeg" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Placeholder Coupon no</h4>
                    <p>Get exiting deals here</p>
                    
                </div>
                <img src="img/americanswan.jpeg" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Placeholder Coupon no</h4>
                    <p>Get exiting deals here</p>
                    
                </div>
                <img src="img/snapdeal.jpeg" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div>      
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Placeholder Coupon no</h4>
                    <p>Get exiting deals here</p>
                    
                </div>
                <img src="img/askmebazaar.jpeg" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div>  
        
  </div>
  
</div><!-- /.container -->

    
  </body>
</html>
```

From the code the coupon no should be retrived from database and stored in placeholder-coupon-no and image src name from store_name and p tag in caption div to be replaced with caption from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to iterate through the results of your query.
You can use the following for reference.

```
<?php 
    $query = "select * from featured_stores"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query)
    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4><?=  $row['no_of_coupons']; ?></h4>
                    <p><?= $row['caption']; ?></p>
                </div>
                <img src="img/" .<?= $row['store_name']; ?> . ".jpeg" alt="...">
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but i want in two rows not in single row

Comment: Use a counter and if condition to manipulate the html as per your need. :). This code is for reference.

Comment: but just shrink the screen and see the grid breaks ,can you find the explaination for it

Comment: That's a different topic , you will have to understand bootstrap grid classes and how they are supposed to be used.  Your code clearly specifies you have not calculated your grids properly. Read from here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: No ready made solutions bro, you are almost there, try to figure out and learn :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php require_once("includes/database.php");?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Ask Coupon | Promotional codes,Coupons,Deals and many more</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hover.css">
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

    <script src="jquery/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();    
 
    $('.thumbnail').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(250); //.fadeIn(250)
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(250); //.fadeOut(205)
        }
    ); 
});
</script> 
   
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php $query = "select store_name,no_of_coupons,caption from featured_stores";
   $result = mysql_query($query);?>
  <?php if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());?>
  
  
<div class="container">
  
    <div class="row">
    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {?>
        
    
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4><?php echo $row["no_of_coupons"]?></h4>
                    <p><?php echo $row["caption"]?></p>
                    
                </div>
                <img src="img/<?php echo $row["store_name"]?>.jpeg" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div>
      <?php
      }?>
      
  </div>
  
</div><!-- /.container --> 




    
  <?php
require_once("includes/database_closing.php"); ?>
    
  </body>
</html>
```